# Jquery not sending Post variables?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, variables, post

Firstly I apologize, my knowledge of jquery is awful but Im learning. I have a major problem with a script Im writing for personal use, driving me up the wall all weekend. The PHP works 100% (tested) its just the jquery that wont send the post variables

The script allows you to add steps along with a picture and a caption, there is a button at the bottom which allows you to either 'remove last step' or 'add another step' limited to a maximum of 10 steps. When using it on a browser and viewing the html it works seamlessly, the name and id changes as required, it works great apart form the fact that after step1 none of the other steps (ie, step2 step3 step4) send the variables upon form submission. I am using method post for the form and below is the javascript and the html for the step adder:

```
 <html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/screen.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

        if(counter>10){
                alert("Only 10 steps allowed");
                return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div style="margin-bottom:25px; height:180px;"><div class="form"><label>Step '+ counter + ': </label>' +
              '<div class="form"><input readonly="readonly" id="step'+ counter + '" type="hidden" name="step'+ counter + '" maxlength="92"size="50" value="step'+ counter + '"/><div class="formholder">Photo &nbsp; <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type="file" class="file" name="pics' + counter + '"/></div></br>' +
              '<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" class="formholder">Title &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:; width:330px;" id="rtitle' + counter + '" type="text" name="rtitle' + counter + '" maxlength="55" size="30"><br /></div></div>' +
              '<div class="formholder"><textarea style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:block; width:370px; height:85px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;" rows="3" cols="49" type="text" name="step' + counter + '" id="step' + counter + '" value="" ></textarea></div></div></div>');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


        counter++;
         });

         $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
              alert("No more steps to remove");
              return false;
           }   

        counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

         });

         $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
          msg += "\n Step " + i + " : " + $('#step' + i).val();
        }
              alert(msg);
         });
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButtoni").click(function () {

        if(counter>30){
                alert("Only 30 ingredients allowed");
                return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'TextBoxDivi' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div style="height: 75px;"><div class="form"><label>Ingredient '+ counter + ': </label>' +
              '<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" size="50" type="text" name="ingredient' + counter + 
              '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="" ></div>' +
              '<div class="form"><label><i>Amount:</i></label>' +
              '<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type="text" id="amount' + counter + 
              '" name="amount' + counter + '" size="15" value="">&nbsp;' +
              ' <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="unit' + counter + 
              '" id="unit' + counter + '">' +
              '<option value="g">g</option>' +
              '<option value="kg">kg</option>' +
              '<option value="lb">lb</option>' +
              '<option value="tsp">tsp</option>' +
              '<option value="tbsp">tbsp</option>' +
              '<option value="cup">cup</option>' +
              '<option value="pint">pint</option>' +
              '<option value="ml">ml</option>' +
              '<option value="l">l</option>' +
              '<option value="bunch">bunch</option>' +
              '<option value="pinch">pinch</option>' +
              '</select></div></div>');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroupi");


        counter++;
         });

         $("#removeButtoni").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
              alert("No more ingredients to remove");
              return false;
           }   

        counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDivi" + counter).remove();

         });

         $("#getButtonValuei").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
          msg += "\n Ingredient " + i + " : " + $('#ingredient' + i).val();
        }
              alert(msg);
         });
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var $tabs = $('#jrtabs').tabs();

            $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

              var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

              if (i != totalSize) {
                  next = i + 2;
                  $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Step &#187;</a>");
              }

              if (i != 0) {
                  prev = i;
                  $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Step</a>");
              }

            });

            $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
                   $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
                   return false;
               });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <div id="jrtabs">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><strong>1</strong>. Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><strong>2</strong>. Images</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><strong>3</strong>. Ingredients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-4"><strong>4</strong>. Steps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-5"><strong>5</strong>. Dietary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment-6"><strong>6</strong>. Additional</a></li>
                </ul>





                    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div>

                        <?php
                            if($_SESSION['id'])
                            {
                            $sql="SELECT * from `users` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
                            $res=mysql_query($sql);
                            $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                            if(!$_POST['update'])
                            {
                            ?>

                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="recipes/addrecipe.php" method="POST">

                                <input readonly="readonly" id="r_id" type="hidden" name="r_id" maxlength="92"size="50" value="<?php $id_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recipe"); $num_id = mysql_num_rows($id_result); $num_recipe = $num_id + 1; echo "$num_recipe";?>">

                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                                    <input style="width:370px; outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" id="title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="92" size="50"><br/>
                                </div>

                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                                    <textarea style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:block; width:370px; height:85px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;" type='text' id='description' name='description' rows="3" cols="49"></textarea><br/>
                                </div>

                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="time">Time</label>
                                    Prep &nbsp;<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" id="prep_time" type="text" name="prep_time" maxlength="4"size="4"> &nbsp;
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="prep_time_unit" id="prep_time_unit">
                                    <option value="Hour">Hour</option>
                                    <option value="Hours">Hours</option>
                                    <option value="Minutes">Minutes</option>
                                    </select> 
                                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Cook &nbsp;<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" id="cook_time" type="text" name="cook_time" maxlength="4"size="4"> &nbsp;
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="cook_time_unit" id="cook_time_unit">
                                    <option value="Hour">Hour</option>
                                    <option value="Hours">Hours</option>
                                    <option value="Minutes">Minutes</option>
                                    </select>   
                                    <br/>
                                </div>

                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="date">Date</label>
                                    Day &nbsp;
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="day" id="day">
                                        <option value="01">01</option>
                                        <option value="02">02</option>
                                        <option value="03">03</option>
                                        <option value="04">04</option>
                                        <option value="05">05</option>
                                        <option value="06">06</option>
                                        <option value="07">07</option>
                                        <option value="08">08</option>
                                        <option value="09">09</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                        <option value="13">13</option>
                                        <option value="14">14</option>
                                        <option value="15">15</option>
                                        <option value="16">16</option>
                                        <option value="17">17</option>
                                        <option value="18">18</option>
                                        <option value="19">19</option>
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="21">21</option>
                                        <option value="22">22</option>
                                        <option value="23">23</option>
                                        <option value="24">24</option>
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="26">26</option>
                                        <option value="27">27</option>
                                        <option value="28">28</option>
                                        <option value="29">29</option>
                                        <option value="30">30</option>
                                        <option value="31">31</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Month &nbsp;
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="month" id="month">
                                        <option value="01">January</option>
                                        <option value="02">Febuary</option>
                                        <option value="03">March</option>
                                        <option value="04">April</option>
                                        <option value="05">May</option>
                                        <option value="06">June</option>
                                        <option value="07">July</option>
                                        <option value="08">August</option>
                                        <option value="09">September</option>
                                        <option value="10">October</option>
                                        <option value="11">November</option>
                                        <option value="12">December</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Year &nbsp;
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="year" id="year">
                                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>

                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="course">Course</label>
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="course" id="course">
                                        <option value="01">01</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div class="dividerlarge">

                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">

                                <label for="pics">Thumbnail:</label>

                                    <div class="formholder">
                                        Title &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:; width:300px;" id="rtitle" type="text" name="rtitle" maxlength="55" size="30">
                                        <br />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="pics"><i>150px x 150px</i></label>
                                        <div class="formholder">
                                        Photo &nbsp; <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type="file" class="file" name="pics"/>
                                    </div>
                                    </br>
                            </div>
                            </br>

                            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                                    <label for="videolink">Video Link</label>
                                    <textarea style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:block; width:370px; height:85px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;" type='text' id='videolink' name='videolink' rows="3" cols="49"></textarea><br/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div class="dividerlarge">

                                <div id='TextBoxesGroupi'>
                                    <div style="height: 75px;" id="TextBoxDiv1i">

                                        <div class="form">
                                            <label>Ingredient 1: </label>
                                                <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type='text' id='ingredient1' name='ingredient1' size="50">
                                        </div><br />
                                        <div class="form">
                                            <label><i>Amount:</i></label>
                                                <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type='text' id='amount1' name='amount1' size="15">&nbsp;

                                            <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="unit1" id="unit1">
                                                <option value="g">g</option>
                                                <option value="kg">kg</option>
                                                <option value="lb">lb</option>
                                                <option value="tsp">tsp</option>
                                                <option value="tbsp">tbsp</option>
                                                <option value="cup">cup</option>
                                                <option value="pint">pint</option>
                                                <option value="ml">ml</option>
                                                <option value="l">l</option>
                                                <option value="bunch">bunch</option>
                                                <option value="pinch">pinch</option>
                                            </select>
                                                <input type="text" name="Other" id="Other" style="display: none;">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left; width: 400px;">
                                    <input style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; background:#f5f5f5; margin-left:95px; font-weight:bold; color:#78AB46;" type='button' value='Click to add ingredient' id='addButtoni'>
                                    <input style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; background:#f5f5f5; font-weight:bold; color:#c16b54;" type='button' value='Click to remove last' id='removeButtoni'>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div class="dividerlarge">

                                <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
                                    <div style="margin-bottom:25px; height:180px;" id="TextBoxDiv1">
                                        <div class="form">
                                            <label>Step 1: </label>
                                            <div class="form">


                                        <input readonly="readonly" id="step1" type="hidden" name="step1" maxlength="92"size="50" value="step1"/>

                                        <div class="formholder">
                                        Photo &nbsp; <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" type="file" class="file" name="pics"/>
                                    </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" class="formholder">
                                        Title &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <input style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:; width:330px;" id="rtitle" type="text" name="rtitle" maxlength="55" size="30"/>
                                        <br />
                                        </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="formholder">
                                            <textarea style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; display:block; width:370px; height:85px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto;" type='text' id='step1' name='step1' rows="3" cols="49"></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float:left; width: 400px;">
                                    <input style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; margin-left:95px; background:#f5f5f5; font-weight:bold; color:#78AB46;" type='button' value='Click to add step' id='addButton'>
                                    <input style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; background:#f5f5f5; font-weight:bold; color:#c16b54;" type='button' value='Click to remove last' id='removeButton'>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div class="dividerlarge">

                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                            <label for="allergy">Allergy:</label>
                                <div class="formholder">

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="gluten" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/gluten.gif"> 
                                    Gluten Free
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="fat" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/fatfree.gif"> 
                                    Fat Free
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="vegan" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/vegan.gif"> 
                                    Vegan
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="vegetarian" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/vegetarian.gif"> 
                                    Vegetarian
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="egg" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png"> 
                                    Egg
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="shellfish" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png"> 
                                    Shellfish
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="dairy" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png"> 
                                    Dairy
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="nuts" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png"> 
                                    Nuts
                                    </label>

                                    <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="lowsodium" value="1" /> <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png"> 
                                    Low Sodium
                                    </label>

                                </div>   
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div id="fragment-6" class="ui-tabs-panel">
                        <div class="dividerlarge">
                        <div style="height:350px;">
                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                        <label for="title">Difficulty</label>
                            <div class="formholder">

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="1" /> 
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beginner
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="2" /> 
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Intermediate
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="3" /> 
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Advanced
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="4" /> 
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/gray_star.png"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Expert
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="5" /> 
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png">
                                    <img class="radios" src="style/images/color_star.png"> 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Professional
                                </label>

                            </div>
                        <br/>
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                        <label for="hot">Heat:</label>
                            <div class="formholder">

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="0" checked="yes"/> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/cold.png"> Not Spicy
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="1" /> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="2" /> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="3" /> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="4" /> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                </label>

                                <label style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5;" class="radios">
                                    <input type="radio" name="hot" value="5" /> 
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                        <img class="radios" src="style/images/chilli.png">
                                </label>
                            </div>   
                        </div> 

                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="form">
                            <label for="hot">Cuisine:</label>
                                <div class="formholder">
                                    <select style="outline: 5px solid #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #A2B1C5; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;" name="cuisine" id="cuisine">
                                        <option value="African">African</option>
                                        <option value="British">British</option>
                                        <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
                                        <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
                                        <option value="Contemporary">Contemporary</option>
                                        <option value="French">French</option>
                                        <option value="Greek">Greek</option>
                                        <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
                                        <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
                                        <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                                        <option value="Lebanese">Lebanese</option>
                                        <option value="Mediterranean">Mediterranean</option>
                                        <option value="Mexican">Mexican</option>
                                        <option value="Middle Eastern">Middle Eastern</option>
                                        <option value="Pacific">Pacific</option>
                                        <option value="North American">North American</option>
                                        <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                                        <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>   
                        </div> 

                            <div class="form">
                                <input style="background: #f5f5f5 url(style/images/tick.png) no-repeat left; width:150px; margin-bottom:25px; margin-left:90px;" type="submit" id="send" value="Save Recipe">
                            </div>  
                        </form>

                        </div></div>



                        <?php
        }   
    }
    else echo "<script language=\"Javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">document.location.href='index.php'</script>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you see any reason it is not sending the data??

I will be eternally greatful for any advice

Comment: How are you certain that it's not sending the variables in the form data?

Comment: Hi Eaolson, in the page it actions I tried to print $_POST['step2']; and even though text was set nothing returned

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps when you call the post function.

(sorry... I'm on my phone /)

```
$.post("something.php", {variable: var}, function(reply)
{
 $('#something').html(reply);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer . .

But I'll give you a good suggestion that would make HTML & JS much cleaner and easier and things much cleaner

Create

```
<!--Add this in your html and set to display none to keep it hidden-->
<div id='toClone' style='display:none'>
   put the html code in here instead of putting it in JS and handling all the single & double quotes..
  and use this syntax   <input id="step{COUNTER}" name="step{COUNTER}" />.............etc
</div>
```

now in your JS

do this :

```
var newHtml = $("#toClone).html();
while(newHtml.indexOf("{COUNTER}")>-1){
    newHtml = newHtml.replace("{COUNTER}",counter);
}
```

now append the newHTML

this is just a cleaner way for cloning instead of writing a lot of html in JS .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what's actually in the form data as it's posted back to the page.

You have:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div...
```

I don't think that's the correct syntax and it gives me a Javascript error in Chrome. There is no 0-argument option for `.after()`. Do you maybe mean `newTextBoxDiv.html().after(...` ?

BTW, I notice you have a hidden input and a textarea with the same name and id for step1. That's not valid HTML. id attributes must be unique. I assume that's the same for the blocks you're generating dynamically.